# C# Populate Tree View with custom structures

Tags: c#, treeview, depth

How can I populate the Tree Views with custom Tree-Structures?
What I'm trying to do:

I have my Actor class with contains an array of Actors (as children, each of them contains another array of children and so on...) and it has an Actor as parent. I just simply want to display them in in a tree view. The actor class is looking like this:

```
class Actor
{
   public List<Actor> Children {get; set;} = new List<Actor>();
   public Actor Parent {get; set;}

   public Actor[] GetChildren()
   {
      return Children.ToArray();
   }
}


private void UpdateSceneryTree()
{
            SceneryStructureView.Nodes.Clear();
            var root = new TreeNode(KerboEngine.CurrentScenery.Name) ImageIndex = 1, SelectedImageIndex = 1 };
            ListScenery(root);
            SceneryStructureView.Nodes.Add(root);
}

        private void ListScenery(TreeNode root)
        {
            foreach (var sco in KerboEngine.CurrentScenery.RootStructures) //root structures are all roots which have no parent.
            {
                TreeNode n = new TreeNode(sco.Name) { Tag = sco };
                List<TreeNode> ns = new List<TreeNode>();
                foreach (var a in sco.GetChilds()) //here we get all childs of them
                    ns.Add(new TreeNode(a.Name) { Tag = a });
                n.Nodes.AddRange(ns.ToArray());
                root.Nodes.Add(n);
            }
        }
```

This code is working but only only in two depths:

[image]

Like you see Child1 of Construct 2 should have 2 children, I can see them with property grid but not in the tree view.

Does anybody know a solution to get and list the Tree View in unlimited depths?

Comment: Trees as a general rule need __recursive__ functions. Try to wrap your head around and google for _'treeview recursive'_ which should bring up many examples..

Comment: I already did but the most were about Files, and Folders wich are not useful for me because theyre using Paths - what i do not have.

Comment: It is all about the principle of a function that calls itself and passes out its own current state. Here are a few [examples](https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=user%3A3152130+recursive) I wrote..

Comment: Ok ill look at them